# Client and server in C how to keep communication

Tags: c, client

I have a simple tcp based client and server written in c, but once I establish a connection after the server sends a message back to the client, the connection stops working. Could you help me fix this - I would like the server to continue receiving/ sending messages to the client.

Code:

Server.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <resolv.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h> 

#define port    5000
#define buf     512

void answer(int);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    int portid;
    int backlog = 10;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    char BUFF[buf];
    int n;
    int received = 0;
    int connfd;

    if(sock == -1){
        perror("socket error");
        exit(errno);
    }   

    memset(&addr,0, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    if(bind(sock, (struct sockaddr*) &addr, sizeof(addr)) == -1){
            perror("bind error");
            exit(errno);
    }

    if(listen(sock, backlog) == -1){
            perror("listen error");
            exit(errno);
    }

    listen(sock, 5);
    struct sockaddr_in cliaddr;
    //struct sockaddr_in addr;
    int cliaddr_len = sizeof(cliaddr);

    while(1){

        connfd = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&cliaddr,&cliaddr_len);
        if(connfd == -1){
            perror("error connfd");
            exit(errno);
        }
        portid = fork();
        if(portid<0)
            perror("error on fork");
        if(portid ==0){
            close(sock);
            answer(connfd);
            exit(0);
        }


        //close(sock);
    }

    close(connfd);
    return 0;

    //close(sock);
    //return 0;
}

void answer(int connfd){
    int n;
    char BUFF[buf];
    memset(BUFF,buf,buf);
    n = read(connfd,BUFF,buf);
    printf("connected: %s",BUFF);
    //received = 1;
    //memset(BUFF,0,buf);
    printf("please enter your message: ");
    memset(BUFF,0,buf);
    fgets(BUFF,buf, stdin);
    n = write(connfd, BUFF,strlen(BUFF));
    if(n<0) err("writing to socket problem");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server is calling fork, then `if(portid ==0){...get and send message...}`, then it loops back to the top of the loop where it tries to `accept()` --- *not* the job of the child, but the child is trying to do that anyway.

Refactor your code to do what you want. Break it into smaller parts that are simple for you to inspect so you can see things like this.

Comment: You moved code around but you didn't change it. You're describing that you want the server to _loop_ once a connection is established, but you haven't written a loop to do that. From your refactoring, putting a loop within the `answer()` function would be appropriate.

Comment: yes, my problem was that I was not looping the send/receive code

Answer (score 0):

This is because you `recv()` data just one time. Use a loop to receive until the client disconnects.

```
    while ((n = read(connfd,BUFF,buf))
    {
       printf("connected: %s",BUFF);
       //received = 1;
       //memset(BUFF,0,buf);
       printf("please enter your message: ");
       memset(BUFF,0,buf);
       fgets(BUFF,buf, stdin);
       n = write(connfd, BUFF,strlen(BUFF));
       if(n<0) err("writing to socket problem");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the data in your child, so once the child is done the program exits, so try to read in the parent and send the data along to the child.

Comment: The parent sends data only once per connection, so it doesn't matter what the child does. That being said, the child has a loop with which it reads and writes until any `err()` call causes it to exit. The post edit deleted the client code but you can review it at http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21456178/revisions to see this.